# Make UDP-RTMP bridge with FFMPEG

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, wowza

I need to make this chain, using computer 2 as a "bridge" between Computer 1 and the streming server.

Computer 1 ----> Computer 2 ----> Streaming server (Wowza).

So I'm trying to set this:
Computer 1 --(via UDP)--> Computer 2 --(Via RTMP)--> Wowza

## What I've tried:

### 1. At Computer 1

**Entry:**

```
ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -f mpegts udp://192.168.0.109:5010
```

**Result:** *Worked*. Computer 1 sends the data correctly.

### 2. At Computer 2

**Entry:**

```
ffmpeg -i upd://192.168.0.109:5010 output.mp4
```

**Result:** *Worked*. Computer 2 gets data correctly. Output.mp4 is generated well.

**Entry:**

```
ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://wowzaServerAddress
```

**Result:** *Worked*. Wowza shows online the video from sample.mp4

**Entry:**

```
ffmpeg -re -i udp://@:5010 -f flv rtmp://wowzaServerAddress
```

**Result:**

*stuck at:*

```
ffmpeg version N-77234-g906c0b7 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg
built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
libavutil 55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
libavcodec 57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
libavformat 57. 20.100 / 57. 20.100
libavdevice 57.0.100 / 57. 0.100
libavfilter 6.21.100 / 6. 21.100
libswscale 4.0.100 / 4. 0.100
libswresample 2. 0.101 / 2. 0.101
libpostproc 54. 0.100 / 54. 0.100
**Entry:**
    ffmpeg -i udp://192.168.0.109:5010 -c:v copy -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://wowzaServerAddress
**Result:**
*... repeated a lot ...*
Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001cef0462200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001cef0462200] no frame!
*... repeated a lot ...*
 Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://192.168.0.109:5010':
 Duration: N/A, start: 128.032333, bitrate: N/A
 Program 1
Metadata:
service_name: RARBG.COM - Spotlight.2015.1080p.WEB-DL.DD5.1.H264-RARBG
service_provider: FFmpeg
Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), 
yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1916x1032 [SAR 1:1 DAR 479:258], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
Stream #0:1[0x101](eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 200 kb/s
[flv @ 000001cef132a1c0] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[flv @ 000001cef132a1c0] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
Output #0, flv, to '**rtmp://wowzaServerAddress**':
Metadata:
encoder: Lavf57.20.100
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 1916x1032 [SAR 
1:1 DAR 479:258], q=2-31, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 90k tbc
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 48000 Hz, stereo, 
200 kb/s
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 - #0:0 (copy)
Stream #0:1 - #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[flv @ 000001cef132a1c0] Malformed AAC bitstream detected: use the audio 
bitstream filter 'aac_adtstoasc' to fix it ('-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc' option with ffmpeg)
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid data found when processing input
[flv @ 000001cef132a1c0] Malformed AAC bitstream detected: use the audio bitstream filter 'aac_adtstoasc' to fix it ('-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc' option with ffmpeg)
[flv @ 000001cef132a1c0] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 000001cef132a1c0] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
Error writing trailer of rtmp://**wowzaServerAddress**: Invalid data found when processing inputframe= 1 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize= 0kB time= 00:00:02.13 bitrate= 1.6kbits/s
video:33kB audio:59kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

**Conversion failed!**

Comment: Have you tried bridging computer 2 => Wowza without storing as a mp4 first?  ex:  ffmpeg -i upd://192.168.0.109:5010 -c:v copy -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://wowzaServerAddress

Comment: Yeah, of course. Saving as mp4 was just a test to see if com2 was reading the UDP input. In the last part, it's shown that code you're suggesting (And the result).

Comment: I would run your output.mp4 through ffprobe (or similar utility) as it looks as though the codecs are messy.  You may even consider not copying the codecs directly, and transcode it on the fly to see if that resolves the issue.  Something like Ex. ffmpeg -i udp://192.168.0.109:5010 -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -f flv rtmp://wowzaServerAddress